# Freely convert between List<T> and IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, linq, list, ienumerable

How can I convert a `List<MyObject>` to an `IEnumerable<MyObject>` and then back again?

I want to do this in order to run a series of LINQ statements on the List, e. g. `Sort()`

Comment: This is the covered in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31708/how-can-i-convert-ienumerablet-to-listt-in-c

Answer (score 148, accepted):

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
IEnumerable<string> myEnumerable = myList;
List<string> listAgain = myEnumerable.ToList();
```

Comment: Beware however that myEnumarable is the same object instance as myList, but listAgain is not the same object instance as myEnumerable. Depending on what you want to do and what myEnumerable is, "List<string> listAgain = myEnumerable as List<string>;" might be better.

Comment: Chrisw: Oh yes, you're right of course, but the IEnumerable<T> interface is immutable so it will not cause problems in that direction and casting back just feels *dirty* when you have a function that will take care of type safety.

Comment: You also could just use the original myList object. (I guess I don't really get the question)

Comment: It's just that if he edits myList then he would be editing myEnumrable, but if he edits listAgain then he wouldn't be editing myEnumerable.

Comment: Don't forget `using System.Linq;` or you won't be able to ToList()

Comment: Thanks @Blankasaurus. Normally, I rely on 'Resolve' to add any missing usings, but VS didn't offer this in the short-cut menu, even though I had a reference to System.Core.

Comment: @TamasCzinege calling .ToList() is definitely safer as you note, but it does of course come with a performance penalty (allocating the new list and copying the data to it).  Sometimes performance considerations dictate dirtier code.

Answer (score 21):

A `List<T>` is an `IEnumerable<T>`, so actually, there's no need to 'convert' a `List<T>` to an `IEnumerable<T>`.
Since a `List<T>` is an `IEnumerable<T>`, you can simply assign a `List<T>` to a variable of type `IEnumerable<T>`.

The other way around, not every `IEnumerable<T>` is a `List<T>` offcourse, so then you'll have to call the `ToList()` member method of the `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Technically, ToList is a member method of System.Linq.Enumerable

Comment: I think you can just cast IEnumerable on List as David say it is it.

Answer (score 9):

A `List<T>` is already an `IEnumerable<T>`, so you can run LINQ statements directly on your `List<T>` variable.

If you don't see the LINQ extension methods like `OrderBy()` I'm guessing it's because you don't have a `using System.Linq` directive in your source file.

You do need to convert the LINQ expression result back to a `List<T>` explicitly, though:

```
List<Customer> list = ...
list = list.OrderBy(customer => customer.Name).ToList()
```

Comment: "If you don't see the LINQ extension methods like OrderBy()"
That was my problem, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Aside: Note that the standard LINQ operators (as per the earlier example) don't change the *existing* list - `list.OrderBy(...).ToList()` will create a new list based on the re-ordered sequence. It is pretty easy, however, to create an extension method that allows you to use lambdas with `List<T>.Sort`:

```
static void Sort<TSource, TValue>(this List<TSource> list,
    Func<TSource, TValue> selector)
{
    var comparer = Comparer<TValue>.Default;
    list.Sort((x,y) => comparer.Compare(selector(x), selector(y)));
}

static void SortDescending<TSource, TValue>(this List<TSource> list,
    Func<TSource, TValue> selector)
{
    var comparer = Comparer<TValue>.Default;
    list.Sort((x,y) => comparer.Compare(selector(y), selector(x)));
}
```

Then you can use:

```
list.Sort(x=>x.SomeProp); // etc
```

This updates the *existing* list in the same way that `List<T>.Sort` usually does.

Comment: A slight correction to this statement: the standard LINQ operators don't change the existing list; instead, they create a new IEnumerable that contains the logic necessary for doing their work. However, this logic isn't actually executed until the IEnumerator is requested.

Comment: @Vojislav - I was meaning in the context of the earlier example ending with `ToList` - I will clarify, though.

Answer (score 1):

### Converting `List<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>`

`List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>` (and many other such as `IList<T>, ICollection<T>`) therefore there is no need to convert a List back to IEnumerable since it already a `IEnumerable<T>`.

Example:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

Person person1 = new Person() { Id = 1, Name = "Person 1" };
Person person2 = new Person() { Id = 2, Name = "Person 2" };
Person person3 = new Person() { Id = 3, Name = "Person 3" };

List<Person> people = new List<Person>() { person1, person2, person3 };

//Converting to an IEnumerable
IEnumerable<Person> IEnumerableList = people;
```

You can also use `Enumerable.AsEnumerable()` method

```
IEnumerable<Person> iPersonList = people.AsEnumerable();
```

---

### Converting `IEnumerable<T>` to `List<T>`

```
IEnumerable<Person> OriginallyIEnumerable = new List<Person>() { person1, person2 };
List<Person> convertToList = OriginallyIEnumerable.ToList();
```

This is useful in [Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17996264/340046).

Answer (score 0):

To prevent duplication in memory, resharper is suggesting this:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
IEnumerable<string> myEnumerable = myList;
List<string> listAgain = myList as List<string>() ?? myEnumerable.ToList();
```

.ToList() returns a new immutable list.  So changes to listAgain does not effect myList in @Tamas Czinege answer.  This is correct in most instances for least two reasons:  This helps prevent changes in one area effecting the other area (loose coupling), and it is very readable, since we shouldn't be designing code with compiler concerns.

But there are certain instances, like being in a tight loop or working on an embedded or low memory system, where compiler considerations should be taken into consideration.