# How to cast list to enumerable

Tags: c#, list, ienumerable, casting

I've got a problem with the following code:

```
public IEnumerable<ISession> GetSessions()
{
    // ...

    using (ProvaDbEntities DBEntities = new ProvaDbEntities(Utilities.ToEntitiesConnectionString()))
    {
        ObjectQuery<session> sessions = DBEntities.session;
        IEnumerable<session> q1 = from session in sessions
                                  where session.site == this.Name
                                  select session;

        List<Session> sessionList = new List<Session>();
        foreach (var s in q1)
        {
            sessionList.Add(new Session(s.id.ToString(),s.username, s.site, new DateTime()));
        }

        IEnumerable<Session> res = sessionList;

        return sessionList;
    }
}
```

The exception is:

> Is not possible to cast object type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[prova3.Session]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TAP2009.AuctionSite.Interfaces.ISession]'.

Looking at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472669/c-freely-convert-between-listt-and-ienumerablet) it seems to be correct. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 5):

It should be fine, so long as `Session` implements `ISession` - *if* you're using C# 4 and .NET 4. If you're not, it won't be.

Note that the question you referred to use the same "T" in both cases - whereas the exception you've got is about converting a `List<Session>` to an `IEnumerable<ISession>`. You haven't stated where you're getting the exception, which makes it a bit harder to see exactly what's going on... Are you sure this is *actually* the code which is failing? Are you sure you're getting an exception rather than a compile-time failure?

EDIT: If you're not using .NET 4 and C# 4, the workaround for covariance is reasonably simple here - use the `Cast<T>()` LINQ operator:

```
return sessionList.Cast<ISession>();
```

Comment: Tank you jon, yes, Session implements the Interface Isession.
The try - catch block is at the beginning and at the end of the come that I posted.
try
            {
                using (ProvaDbEntities DBEntities = new ProvaDbEntities(Utilities.ToEntitiesConnectionString()))
...
Yes, I'm sure, I'getting an exception
return res;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new UnavailableDbException("[GetSessions!!-------------- (site)]" + e.Message);
            }

Comment: @trifabbio: By throwing a new exception you're hiding which line it's being thrown on. (Catching Exception is generally a bad idea too.) The weird thing is that your code doesn't show any casts. Are you sure you don't have a cast in the return statement or assignment to res?

Comment: Yes jon, I've a cast..
List<Session> sessionList = new List<Session>();
                    foreach (var s in q1)
                    {
                        sessionList.Add(new Session(s.id.ToString(),s.username, s.site, new DateTime()));
                    }
                        IEnumerable<Session> res = sessionList;

                        return (IEnumerable<ISession>)res;
If I don't make a cast in the return line I obtain a static error and I can' compile.
I commfirm that the class Session Implement the Interface ISession.
I'm becaming crazy..

Comment: @trifabbio: Right. So the code you've posted isn't the code you've got... *please* don't do that again. How are we meant to debug errors when we can't see your code? I suspect you're using .NET 3.5 or lower - which doesn't support generic covariance - as per my first sentence. It would *also* have been useful if you'd posted what platform you're using from the start. I'll edit my answer with a workaround.

Comment: I'm sorry jon, you're right. 
Yes, i'using .NET 3.5. SP1.
Tanks
Fabio

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the extension method AsEnumerable()?

So this line

```
IEnumerable<Session> res = sessionList;
```

Would change to

```
IEnumerable<Session> res = sessionList.AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: Why would that help? `List<T>` already implements `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

The return type is public `IEnumerable<ISession>`, i forgot to specify the type of the `Ienumerable`..

Answer (score 0):

You can add `using System.Linq` and use the extension method `Cast<T>` that returns a `IEnumerable<T>`.