# linq System.ObjectDisposedException

Tags: linq, dispose, entities

i have a problem with some data i retrievied from db with linq.
When I try to access data I obtain the following exception:
System.ObjectDisposedException : The istance of ObjectContext was deleted and is not possible to use it again for action that need a connection.
This is the code:

```
using (ProvaDbEntities DBEntities =     
    new ProvaDbEntities(Utilities.ToEntitiesConnectionString()))

            {
                ObjectQuery<site> sites = DBEntities.site;

                IEnumerable<site> q = from site in sites

                                      select site;


                {
                    ObjectQuery<auction> auctions = DBEntities.auction;

                    IEnumerable<auction> q1 = from auction in auctions

                                              where auction.site == this.Name

                                              select auction;

                    IEnumerable<IAuction> res = q1.Cast<IAuction>();

                    return res;

            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw new UnavailableDbException("[GetAuctions]" + e.Message);
        }
```

Someone can help me???
Tanks
Fabio

Answer (score 3):

Yes - you're returning a result which will be *lazily evaluated* - but you're disposing of the data context which would be used to fetch the results.

Options:

- Load the results eagerly, e.g. by calling `ToList` on the result
- Don't dispose of the context (I don't know what the situation is in the Entity Framework; you could get away with this in LINQ to SQL, but it may not be a good idea in EF)
- Dispose of the context when you're finished with the data

In this case I'd suggest using the first option - it'll be safe and simple. As you're already filtering the results *and* you're casting to `IEnumerable<IAuction>` anyway, you're unlikely to get the normal downsides of materializing the query early. (If it were still `IQueryable<T>`, you'd be throwing away the ability to add extra bits to the query and them still be translated to SQL.)

Comment: Hi Jon, 
  I tried the firf option but I obteined an invalidCastException..
You mean somethink like this?

//IEnumerable<IAuction> res = q1.Cast<IAuction>();
IEnumerable<IAuction> res2 = q1.ToList().Cast<IAuction>();
return res2;

Comment: @trifabbio: Not quite - you don't need to call `Cast` again. But if you're getting a cast exception, that suggests the objects being created just aren't implementations if `IAuction`.

Comment: Is the same problem that I (you :) ) solved here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075393/how-to-cast-list-to-enumerable ..
I'm confused :(

Comment: Hi jon I'm still blocked here.. 
Now the situation is this:
If I do IEnumerable<IAuction> res = q1.Cast<IAuction>();
I have an exception because ObjectContext was deleted.
If I convert my result to a list I have an exception because NET 3.5 or lower - doesn't support generic covariance.
Tank you for your answers
Fabio

Comment: @trifabbio: Convert it to a list and *then* call `Cast<IAuction>`. You can do that later cast at any point, because the data's already been grabbed by then.