# How to convert List<string> to IEnumerator<string>

Tags: c#, linq

I know the basics of List and IEnumerator but still I confused with this. I want to search valid URLs from a string. I can extract the valid URLs by LINQ but I would like to use IEnumerator GetEnumerator() of MatchCollection.

```
string url = @"http://www.ms.com http://www.hemelix.com http://www.cgi.com";
string pattern = @"http://(www\.)?([^\.]+)\.com";

List<string> result = new List<string>();
MatchCollection myMatches = Regex.Matches(url, pattern);
result = (
    from System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match m in myMatches 
    select m.Value
).ToList<string>();

var result2 = from Match m in myMatches 
              select m.Value;

foreach (var item in result2)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}

// Does the following code work in this case??
result = (List<string>)myMatches.GetEnumerator();
// OR the following
IEnumerator<string> enumerator = (IEnumerator<string>) (myMatches.GetEnumerator()); 
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    Console.WriteLine(enumerator.Current);
}
```

Comment: [Freely convert between `List<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/472669/447156)?

Comment: Have you read this? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0yss765%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: In C# you rarely use IEnumerator. Typically you use IEnumerable with a foreach loop, which handles the creation and progression of the IEnumerator for you. Is there a particular reason that you want to use the enumerator manually?

Answer (score 3):

You can't convert a List to IEnumerator, that are totally different things. 
The List implements IEnumerable, and Enumerator is something for iterating an IEnumerable.

Your (corrected) code

```
IEnumerator enumerator = myMatches.GetEnumerator();
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    Console.WriteLine(enumerator.Current);
}
```

does the same as

```
foreach (var item in myMatches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Comment: Actually no, and worse, the latter wraps the code above in a try/finally block to call Dispose() on the enumerator in case it is disposable.

Comment: Thanks. is it because IEnumerator is returned from GetEnumerator() not IEnumerator<string>? Can I get List<string> from IEnumerator? Looks those are totally different type.

Comment: @RotatingWheel no, an Enumerator is like a pointer to the position in the List or other IEnumerable (List implements IEnumerable). It just knows there you currently are in the list.

Comment: @RotatingWheel then you call GetEnumerator() on myMatches, you will get the MatchEnumerator, which implements IEnumerator interface. If you need a List, you will have to create it first using the data contained in myMatches

Comment: @OguzOzgul not in this case, MatchEnumerator doesn't implement IDisosable

Comment: Yes. But still, for each statement will test it. that's why for each is better. If one day he uses a disposable enumerator this way, for each will dispose it automatically right after the loop

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pretty easy way via Linq to convert your `MatchCollection` into a `IEnumerable<string>` object but this is similar to what you already did in your Linq with Query Syntax. This would just be a Method Syntax version.

```
IEnumerable<string> matches = myMatches.Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value);
foreach (var match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match);
}
```

Result:

```
http://www.ms.com
http://www.hemelix.com
http://www.cgi.com
http://www.ms.com
http://www.hemelix.com
http://www.cgi.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Primarily `IEnumerable<T>` operations are returned out of a method which actually would need to do it in an item by item way such as MoveNext. Frankly Regex provides a list of matches all at once; so I am not seeing the benefit of returning `IEnumerable`.

---

With that said here are two methods which achieve the same return

```
public static class MyOperations
{

public static string Pattern = @"https?://(www\.)?(?<Url>[^\s]+)";
public static Regex RegexHTTP = new Regex(Pattern, RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);

public static IEnumerable<string> GetUrl(this string text)
{
    return RegexHTTP.Matches(text)
                    .OfType<Match>()
                    .Select (mt => mt.Groups["Url"].Value);
}

public static IEnumerable<string> GetUrlEx(this string text)
{
    var urls = RegexHTTP.Matches(text)
                    .OfType<Match>()
                    .Select (mt => mt.Groups["Url"].Value);

    foreach (var url in urls)
        yield return url;

}
```

**Test Harness**

```
string urls = "http://www.ms.com http://www.hemelix.com http://www.cgi.com http://omegacoder.com";

Console.WriteLine ("GetUrl:");
foreach (string url in urls.GetUrl())
    Console.WriteLine ("\t" + url);

Console.WriteLine ("{0}GetUrlEx:", Environment.NewLine);
foreach (string url in urls.GetUrlEx())
    Console.WriteLine ("\t" + url);
```

**Resultant Output**

```
GetUrl:
  ms.com
  hemelix.com
  cgi.com
  omegacoder.com

GetUrlEx:
  ms.com
  hemelix.com
  cgi.com
  omegacoder.com
```