# The model is of type List, but this dictionary requires IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my controller I have a simple LINQ query:

```
var results = .....ToList();
```

Then, I want to pass 'results' into a View that renders a grid.  It takes a model of:

```
@model IEnumerable<XXXX.WebSite.Areas.BrokerDashboard.Models.AccountHBSearchItem>
```

I didn't think this would be a problem, but I get:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List, but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

This confuses me, because from all that I'm reading, a `List<T>` already is an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Based on an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472669/freely-convert-between-listt-and-ienumerablet), I tried this:

```
IEnumerable<string> eResults = results.ToList();
```

But that gets me the `Can implicitly convert` error.

If I don't do the `.ToList()` then `results` is an IOrderedEnumerable, and I get this:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable, but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

**EDIT:**

This is the entire query:

```
            var results = Context.GetLeadSalesAccountTransactions(accountID)
            .OrderBy(a => a.TransactionDate)
           .Select(a =>
           {
               currentTotal -= a.Debit != null ? (decimal)a.Debit : 0;
               currentTotal += a.Credit != null ? (decimal)a.Credit : 0;
               return new AccountHBSearchItem
               {
                   AccountTransactionID = a.AccountTransactionID,
                   LeadID = a.LeadSales != null ? a.LeadSales.Lead.LeadID : 0,
                   Address = a.LeadSales != null ? a.LeadSales.Lead.Address : string.Empty,
                   LotNumber = a.LeadSales != null ? a.LeadSales.Lead.LotNumber : string.Empty,
                   Type = a.AccountTransactionType.GetDisplayName(),
                   Debit = a.Debit,
                   Credit = a.Credit,
                   RemainingBalance = currentTotal,
                   TransDate = a.TransactionDate
               };
           }
                  ).OrderByDescending(i => i.TransDate).ToList();
```

Comment: Could you please post the whole query as well as the Definition of `MyModel`? Thanks

Comment: You can pass a `List<T>` to a view strongly typed to`IEnumerable<T>`. Are your types different ?

Comment: i think you can do foo.Objects.AsEnumerable(); in your linq statement

Comment: I've posted the entire query, and updated the @model to show the real thing, minus the name of the client.  THANKS!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you have different type of generic parameters of your `List<T1>` and `IEnumerable<T2>`. From your seccond attempt I see that you are using `IEnumerable<string>` but model is `IEnumerable<MyNamespace.MyModel>`. Make sure generic parameters are same. You can pass

- `List<MyNamespace.MyModel>`
- `IEnumerable<MyNamespace.MyModel>`
- `IOrderedEnumerable<MyNamespace.MyModel>`

All of them are appropriate

Comment: ok, I see what you are saying.  I *think* I got it all right?  I updated the OP with more details, including the full name of the @model

Comment: I shouldn't have said, "I think I got it all right."  Obviously I didn't... just not sure what I missed.  And THANK YOU!

Comment: @CaseyCrookston it there any chance that you have two classes `AccountHBSearchItem` in different namespaces? E.g. one in Models, and other goes from data layer?

Comment: ... ahhh.... as a matter of fact.  Lemme change on of them.

Comment: changing, but in the mean time, why would it matter?  I thought the different name spaces wouldn't cause problems

Comment: @CaseyCrookston *duck typing* is not working in c# :) if classes have same set of fields and same name, but different namespace - they are still different

Answer (score 0):

The return type of the .ToList will be of type`<T>`.

This means that `<T>` can be anything that implements a particular interface or is a particular concrete/abstract class. This depends on the class that is using the Generics and returning the List of those `<T>` objects.

Using an interface constraint on `<T>` means that you can accept a `<T>` (or `List<T>`) without knowing what type of object `<T>` actually is, but still interact with specific properties or methods according to the interface that `<T>` must implement.

The `@model` that will be used in the Razor View is specified as an `IEnumerable` (a list that you can iterate through) of type `xxx.AccountHBSearchItem`.
You can then access the properties and methods that are available in `AccountHBSearchItem` from `@model`.
For example: `@model.AccountTransactionID, @model.LeadId`, etc.

But the `List<T>` isn't a `List<xxx.AccountHBSearchItem>` - it could be anything. So Razor will not be able to access the properties and methods that you will use on the View for output because it cannot guarantee that the `<T>` object has an interface that fits. You could be passing a `List<Animal>` to the View, and any access to properties that `xxx.AccountHBSearchItem` has will fail (I'd hope!) because an `Animal` isn't a `xxx.AccountHBSearchItem`.

So, to solve this problem, you could state in the class used to generate the `List<T>` that `<T>` implements the interface that you need to use when generating the View.

Suppose the interface needs the following properties (guessed from your data); create an interface with these properties, to be used on all of the classes that will be used as a `<T>`.

```
public interface IAccountHBSearchItem
{
    long AccountTransactionID { get; set; }
    long LeadID { get; set; }
    string Address { get; set; }
    string LotNumber { get; set; }
    string Type { get; set; }
    bool Debit { get; set; }
    bool Credit { get; set; }
    decimal RemainingBalance { get; set; }
    DateTime TransDate { get; set; }
}
```

Now specify that the different classes implement this interface:

```
public class AccountSearchAAA<T> where T : IAccountHBSearchItem
{
    // Rest of implementation
    public List<T> GetAll()
    {
        // return list of AccountSearchAAA objects here
    }
}

public class AccountSearchBBB<T> where T : IAccountHBSearchItem
{
    // Rest of implementation
    public List<T> GetAll()
    {
        // return list of AccountSearchBBB objects here
    }
}
```

Then you can change `@model` to use `IEnumerable<xxx.IAccountHBSearchItem>` (the interface).

Now you can generate search results of different account types for instance, as long as they implement this interface, and then use them all on the same View.

Accessing the properties and methods available via the interface will now be fine.